# Get Local Time from a given IP Address

Tags: php, ip-address

Good day

I just want to ask on how to get the local date and time from a given IP Address using PHP.. I'm developing a system that gets its time from an IP Address, not in the Computer's time. I am new in php so find it difficult for me.

I saw a website that gets a local time from an ip address:
**http://(youripaddress).ipaddress.com/**
change (youripaddress) with an ip address you want to get information
Here is an example: (I shaded black the other information for some purpose)
[image: Local Time]

The image above shows that from a given IP Address, they get the Local time, I'm wondering how did they get the local time from an IP Address.. Is it possible to do in PHP? How? Thanks a lot guys..

Comment: They check where the ip is located then check the time in the country.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a location method where you see which country / area the IP is located in then get that info and try to get the timezone in that area and output the time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use **[GeoLite2](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/)**, which tells you the timezone by IP address. It has a local PHP API.

***Note***: IP address can't even be relied upon to map to a country. Its better to have the client send you the time zone, perhaps in a header.